# Prove that $S$is a closed subspace of $H^2$ invariant under multiplication by $z$. Find the inner function $F$ such that $S=FH^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, hardy-spaces

Let ${\alpha_n}$ be a sequence of points in the open unit disc such that $\sum(1-|\alpha_n|)<\infty$. Let $S$ be the set of all functions $f$ in $H^2$ spaces such that $f(\alpha_n)=f'(\alpha_n)=0$ for each $n$. Prove that $S$ is a closed subspace of $H^2$ invariant under multiplication by $z$. Find the inner function $F$ such that $S=FH^2$.

Comment: What is $\,H^2\,$ ??

Comment: Hilbert space $H^2$

Comment: **What** Hilbert space?!

Comment: And what is an "inner function"??

Comment: the question in book `Banach spaces is analytic function`-author Kenneth Hoffman in page 119, exersises 1, I want to solve it, but I can not, please help me sir

Comment: I've already explained in the past: I demand that any student in high-school level or above be **at least** able to explain what is he asking. If you can't then you *first* must understand the basic elements in your question *and then* pose the question...

Comment: This is not a book with which I am doing in school, I landed a book from the internet, and try to solve the task by some

Comment: excuse, no I`m not

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm assuming the OP probably means the Hardy space $H^2$ on the unit disc which consists of all holomorphic functions on the disc whose $L^2(C_r)$-norms stay bounded as $r \to 1$.

Comment: Oh, @brom: I'm almost certain he meant that, in particular because I read it in the book which the OP mentions, incorrectly btw since the title is Banach Spaces **of** Analytic Functions. It's just that I'm becoming less and less forgiving with certain sloppy-written questions. This one, for example, must be from a 2-3 year undergraduate level at least, and I think the question must be understood (not solved, of course) by the asker.

Answer (score 0):

I think the others gave you unnecessarily a hard time: your question is very clear for anyone knowing what Hardy spaces are (and that's one of your tags).

Proof that $S$ is invariant under $M_z$ (multiplication by $z$): take a function $f \in H^2$ such that $f(\alpha_i)=0$ and $f'(\alpha_i)=0$ for some $i \in N$ (natural numbers). Define $g(z)=zf(z)$ ($g=M_zf$). Evaluate $g$ and $g'$ at $z=\alpha_i$ and you will see that the result is again 0. So if you start with a function in $S$, the result is again in $S$.

To proof that $S$ is closed in an elementary way, take a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_n \in S \forall n$ and suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ (in Hardy norm). Since Hardy norm convergence is stronger than uniform convergence over compacta, that implies $f_n$ converge pointwise to $f$ and $f'_n$ converge pointwise to $f'$ on compact subsets of the disc. Hence $f$ is in $S$.

To find the inner function $F$ that makes $S= FH^2$, note that that function must have a zero of order two at each of the points $\alpha_i$, and that no other condition is required. So the square of the Blaschke product with zeros at those points is exactly your function $F$. I let you do the details to prove this, but anyway, the fact that the $\alpha_i$'s satisfy the Blaschke condition guarantees that $F$ is a valid Blaschke product.